# html does not send post to view

Tags: python, html, django, post, django-views

I have a submit form like:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="id_active_state">
            <div class="icheckbox_square-red checked" style="position: relative;">
                <input type="checkbox" name="active_state" class="" id="id_active_state" checked=""><ins class="iCheck-helper"></ins>
            </div> active</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">

    <div class="button_holder">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="send">
            submit
        </button>
    </div>

</div>
```

and it should be handled in view:

```
def special_offer_edit_view(http_request):
    action_verbose_name = 'the_view'
    special_offer_id = http_request.GET.get('id')
    special_offer_obj = SpecialOffer.objects.filter(id=special_offer_id)
    for data in special_offer_obj:
        sp_obj = {'active_state': data.active_state}

    if http_request.method == 'POST':
        print('hi')

    return render(...)
```

it raises 503 error, and does not send "POST" method and data. what is its problem?

Comment: You're missing a `<form action="whereYourActionTakesPlace" method="POST">` around your input fields and submit button. Your fields do not know that a) they should use post (method) and b) where it should point to (action).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input should be accessed by element name `active_state` you have given otherwise

like this will be `None`

```
special_offer_id = http_request.GET.get('id')
```

Your `render(...)` should return HttpResonse with existing template

```
render(http_request,"template.html",{"context" : 2})
```

Set `DEBUG=True` in settings to get the error log

Embed the html in with `csrf_token`

```
<form method="POST">
<!-- Your html here -->
{% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

Comment: render is just like what you wrote, also I used ````<form method="POST">```` at the beginning of HTML file.

Comment: Did you get the error log? Otherwise it is difficult to help

Comment: I didn't used this line ````{% csrf_token %}```` 
,it made it right. Tnx

Comment: You can find more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/)